# What does 'Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]' mean in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I keep getting this error:

> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
> [object Object]

There is no line number or anything associated with it. It comes from this script:
http://www.fissiondesigns.com/simon/. Try drawing a square on the picture to reproduce.

What does the error mean and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst in dev/debug it helps not to use the minified versions of js libraries as you tend to get nonsensical errors.

Try including the full jquery/ui versions first to get better error info.

Answer (score 2):

Script you are using has some kind of parser. It should have sth like this:

`throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + object.toString()`

where object is some json instead of string in your case.
I would check the configuration options for widget you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with jQuery 1.4.2 + jQuery UI 1.8.2?  It's a general law of computer science: **always use the latest version**. Bugs age getting fixed, design flaws are getting cleared up, etc.